# How can I find a report of dividend earned in a FY?

Tags: income-tax, india, dividends

(My first post here, gently...)

I have been in the stock market for over a year now. I have been trading via an account with Kotak Securities. I am now filing my taxes and need to know the total dividend accrued during FY 2013-2014. I am assuming that my <s>broker</s> broker (?) would provide me that information.

This information is probably included in some report provided on my borker's website. What would such a report be called?

Comment: Actually, I like the typo "borker". Expresses my feelings about many of them rather nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is old.
I also have a kotak trading account. There is no way to get the dividend report from the trading account. The dividend is directly credited to your bank account by the companies through registrar. There is no involvement of trading account in there. So the best possible way will be to get the bank account statement for the financial year and filter out the dividend transactions manually. I know it is tedious, but there doesn't seem to be any easy way out there for this.

Few days back I started using portfolio manager provided by economic times. It lists all the dividend earned in my stocks automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to kotak securities demat account. THere, you can find statement of your sell purchase and dividend received.

Comment: Are you sure the statement shows the dividend received? Could not find that. Also, when I called customer support they said I can only get that information from my bank statement where the dividend credit is noted.